# Share 2 data to all view in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel

I want to share this data to all views with laravel 4.2

But, can I use array to pass this 2 data with `View::share()`?

```
    class Sidebar extends BaseController {
    public function __construct() {
        $package_sidebar = TravelPackage::orderBy('idTravelPackage','DESC')->take(4)->get();
        $artikel_sidebar = Artikel::orderBy('date','DESC')->take(4)->get();

        View::share()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in your routes.php or somewhere else more appropriate:

```
<?php

View::share('package_sidebar', TravelPackage::orderBy('idTravelPackage','DESC')->take(4)->get());
View::share('artikel_sidebar', Artikel::orderBy('date','DESC')->take(4)->get());
```

Then you'll be able to reference `$package_sidebar` and `$artikel_sidebar` in any view.